# Ruby Regular Expressions: Matching if substring doesn't exist

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm having an issue trying to capture a group on a string:

```
"type=gist\nYou need to gist this though\nbecause its awesome\nright now\n</code></p>\n\n<script src=\"https://gist.github.com/3931634.js\"> </script>\n\n\n<p><code>Not code</code></p>\n"
```

My regex currently looks like this:

```
/<code>([\s\S]*)<\/code>/
```

My goal is to get everything in between the code brackets.  Unfortunately, it's matching up to the 2nd closing code bracket  Is there a way to match everything inside the code brackets up until the first occurrence of ending code bracket?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All repetition quantifiers in regular expressions are greedy by default (matching as many characters as possible). Make the `*` ungreedy, like this:

```
/<code>([\s\S]*?)<\/code>/
```

But **please** consider using a DOM parser instead. Regex is just not the right tool to parse HTML.

Comment: Don't worry, I'm only doing this as an exercise.  If I really needed to parse html I'd be using a DOM parser.

Comment: @JackSlingerland in this case, you shall be forgiven ;). [Here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) is a really good tutorial on regular expressions with [this article](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) applying specifically to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

And I just learned that for going through multiple parts, the

```
String.scan( /<code>(.*?)<\/code>/ ){
  puts $1
}
```

is a very nice way of going through all occurences of **code** - but yes, getting a proper parser is better...